# How to integrate DocuSign with Workday

Tags: docusignapi, docusignconnect

I want to integrate DocuSign with WorkDay? As far as I know to integrate or to connect with other applications we need to go to Integration and then connect, and finally we need to add configuration  .
And to connect with external application we need to click on Custom and this window pops out
and we need to give the url to publish .
So basically what should be the url with respect to  workday

Answer (score 0):

The Workday configuration would be providing this, I assume. I'm not sure how the integration works but when you connect it to your account, the integration should create the connect configuration for you. There doesn't seem to be a generic URL for the connect events to publish anyway. You might have to check with Workday Support.